# Translate `numpy` operation for Pandas DataFrame to equivalent for PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to translate a `numpy` lambda function to its equivalent for a PySpark data frame. I have been struggling to find the correct functions/methods.

I conduct the following operation on a Pandas dataframe to generate a new column, `label`, for `panda_stack`:

```
panda_stack['label'] = panda_stack.groupby('id')['prob1'].transform(lambda x: 0.0 if all(np.isnan(x)) else 1.0)
```

Basically, I have:

```
id   prob1
id1  NA
id1  0.12
id2  NA
```

and want:

```
id  label
id1 1
id2 0
```

Can someone please help me translate the above code to something that does the same for a PySpark Data Frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collect_list` and apply the same `numpy lambda` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

check_udf = F.udf(lambda x: 0.0 if all(np.isnan(x)) else 1.0, FloatType())

df = df.groupyby('id').agg(F.collect_list('prob1').alias('label'))\
       .select('id', check_udf(F.col('label').alias('label'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't come out with a straight forward answer. But till someone else answers you can use below code

```
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, np.nan), (1, 0.12), (2, np.nan)], ('id', 'prob1'))

df = df.withColumn(
    'prob1',
    F.when(
        F.col('prob1') == 0,
        F.lit(0.01)
    ).otherwise(
        F.col('prob1')
    )
)

df = df.fillna(0)

df = df.groupBy('id').agg(
    F.sum(F.col('prob1')).alias('label')
)

df = df.withColumn(
    'label',
    F.when(
        F.col('label') != 0,
        F.lit(1)
    ).otherwise(
        F.col('label')
    )
)

df.show()
```